# Can I use a omnetpp.ini variable in my class?

Tags: c++, omnet++, ini

in my project I'm building a network of UEs and ENb (5G) and have different amounts of UEs and following ENb gates

```
[Config SingleUE]
project3.numberOfUes = 1
project3.ENb.numberOfGates = 1

[Config MultiUE]
project3.numberOfUes = 10
project3.ENb.numberOfGates = 10
```

In my class I want to check if any of the UEs have sent a message with equal numbers and at the end if my msgCounter is equal to the numberOfGates I want so send out all messages saved in an vector array

```
if(msgCounter == numberOfGates)
        {
            for(uint i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++)
            {
               EV<<"sending RACH-Response";
               RAP *msg = generateMessage2();
               send(msg,"out", 0);
               delete msg;
            }
        }
```

but this numberOfGates isn't the same as in the omnetpp.ini file, so my question is if there is any method or smth else that I can set the variable in my class?

Answer (score 1):

okay I found the answer

```
numberOfGates = par("numberOfGates");
```

with this I can link the two parameters